# Mark a cell with the highest number in each row in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I'm sorry that I'm an idiot. But I have one last thing to do
First, here my code:

```
package einlesen;

/**
 * @author angeliqueschulberger
 *
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class Einlesen {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    static List<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();                                                     //Instanzierung der Liste
    static Map<String, Integer> wordsInTheMiddle = new HashMap<>();                                         //Instanzierung der Hashmap
    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource" })

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);                                                              //Scanner einfügen
        String antwort;                                                                                     //Antwort bekommen

        System.out.println("Welches Dokument wollen Sie? Geben Sie dabei den Path an, bitte.");             //Frage dür Antwort
        antwort =  scan.nextLine();                                                                         //Antwort einschreiben

        String path = System.getProperty("user.home");                                                      //Damit das Programm auf das Verzeichnis greifen kann
        File file = Paths.get(path, antwort).toFile();

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(br);                                                                       //Liest die Text-Datei

        while (sc.hasNext()) {                                                                              //Löscht Gänseblümchen aus dem Text
            String wort = sc.next();
            if (wort.startsWith("\"")) {                                                                    //Am Anfang
                wort = wort.substring(1);
            }
            if (wort.endsWith("\"")) {                                                                      //Und am Ende
                wort = wort.substring(0, wort.length() - 1);
            }
            word.add(wort);                                                                                 //Jedes einzelne Wort wir in eine ArrayList eingefügt
        }

        br.close();                                                                                         //Beendet das lesen, wenn es keine Wörter mehr gibt

        int chunkStartIndex = 0;                                                                            //Anfang des ersten 2000-wörtrigen Teiles

        List<Map<String,Integer>> wordsPerChunck = new ArrayList<>();                                       //Instanziert eine Liste für Wörter pro Teil
        int chunckNumber = 0;                                                                               //Die NUmmer des 1.Teils ist 0

        while (word.size() - chunkStartIndex > 0) {                                                         //Solange es wörter gibt

            int chunkEndIndex = chunkStartIndex + 2000;                                                     //Das Ende eines Teiles ist nach 2000 Wörter
            if (chunkEndIndex > word.size()) {                                                              //Geht der End Index des Teiles über das letzte Wort hinaus, ist der End Index des letzten Teiles beim Ende der Liste
                chunkEndIndex = word.size();
            }
            List<String> chunkOfWords = word.subList(chunkStartIndex, chunkEndIndex);                       //Die Wörter werden in Teile je 2000 Wörter max aufgeteilt

            Map<String, Integer> countInChunck = new HashMap<>();                                           //Wörter pro Teil wird gezählt, der letzte Teil könnte ja Probleme machen
            wordsPerChunck.add(countInChunck);

            for (int i = 0; i < chunkOfWords.size(); i++) {                                                 //Jetzt kommen die Filter

                String word1 = chunkOfWords.get(i);                                                         //Wir nehmen jedes einzelne word der verschiedenen Teile und sehen ob die Patterns stimmen

                if (word1.matches("[A-Z][a-z][a-z]\\w+")) {                                                 //Pattern für groß geschriebene Wörter, mit mehr als 3 Buchstaben
                    wordsInTheMiddle.putIfAbsent(word1, 0);                                                 //Wenn das Wort nicht passt, dann schreiben wir einfach 0 hin
                    int oldCount = wordsInTheMiddle.get(word1);                                             //Die Nummern werden dann zusammen gezählt
                    wordsInTheMiddle.put(word1, oldCount + 1);
                    countInChunck.putIfAbsent(word1, 0);                    
                    countInChunck.put(word1, countInChunck.get(word1) + 1);                                 //Es wird gezählt

                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < chunkOfWords.size() - 1; i++) {                                             // Wir prozessieren nicht das letzte Wort, sonst gibt es eine OutOfBounds Exception

                String word1 = chunkOfWords.get(i);                                                         //Von der LIste 

                if (word1.matches("\\w*(\\.|\\?|!)$")) {                                                    //Wörter die am Ende eines Satzen stehen

                    // Word is at end of sentence
                    String nextWord = chunkOfWords.get(i + 1);                                              //Das nächste Wort davon

                    if (wordsInTheMiddle.getOrDefault(nextWord, 0) < 2) {

                                                                                                            //Wörter die am Anfang eines Satzes vorkommen
                                                                                                            //und die mehr als 2 Mal im Text vorkommen
                        wordsInTheMiddle.remove(nextWord);

                    }

                }

            }

                                                                                                            //Wörter die wie eigene Namen geschrieben werden, aber keine sind können wir löschen
            String[] blacklist = { "This", "When", "Night", "Most", "Stone", "There", "Bonfire", "Tuesday", "Their",                
                    "They", "Professor", "Famous", "About", "Madam", "Nearly", "Aunt", "What", "Uncle", "Mommy",
                    "Scars", "Scotch", "Every", "That" };
            for (String listedWord : blacklist) {

                wordsInTheMiddle.remove(listedWord);

            }


            System.out.println("Mitte: " + wordsInTheMiddle);

            chunkStartIndex = chunkEndIndex;

        }


        JTable t = new JTable(toTableModel(wordsInTheMiddle, wordsPerChunck));                                                  //Und nun die GUI: Erstmal die Tabelle erstellen

        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(t.getModel());
        t.setRowSorter(sorter);

        List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>(25);
        sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(1, SortOrder.DESCENDING));
        sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(t);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.add(p);
        f.setSize(700, 600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setTitle(antwort);
        }


    public static TableModel toTableModel(Map<?, ?> map, List<Map<String, Integer>> list) {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] { "Key", "Value" }, 0);
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {

            for (int a = word.size()/2000;model.getColumnCount() - 2 <= a;)
            {
                model.addColumn(new Object[] { "partial" });

            }
            Object[] temp = new Object[2+list.size()];
            temp[0] = entry.getKey();
            temp[1] = entry.getValue();

            int index = 2;
            for (Object o : list) {

                Map<?, ?> m = (Map<?, ?>) o;
                // Get the chunck-specific count with the correct key (the name)
                temp[index] = m.get(temp[0]);
                index++;
            }
            model.addRow(temp);



        }
        return model;


    }

}
```

This code produces a table in which the number of times a name appears in a text for different parts is shown. Now I have everything in Order, but I need the header and to change the colour of the cell with the highest number (not including the total of times a name appears in the whole text).
I Hope someone can help me this last time.

Comment: Did you already have a look at the table cell renderer? It's used to format cells/rows/columns based on e.g. values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071668/cell-renderer-for-jtable-coloured-rows

Comment: Yes, I looked it up and tried to implement it. But it was useless for me,I think because of me