# Disable JTable cell editable when other cell value changes

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Let's say I have a JTable with two columns, A and B.
Let's say I also have a List/Vector/Array (any collection) that contains some Strings.
When I am done editing cell at row x, column A (pressing enter or selecting another cell or component), I want the JTable to check if what I typed in column A at row x is in my List. If it is the case, I want to disable editing in Column B at row X and set that cell to "Ok".

I have no idea how to do this. I have searched but found some cases that were different from mine.

Any help will be greatly apreciated.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a custom table model. The TableModel interface contains a method [isCellEditable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29) with wich you can controll this behaviour. To render a cell with "OK" and maybe a colored background you have to use a custom [CellRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563799/jtable-cellrenderer-changes-backgroundcolor-of-cells-while-running)

Comment: Hey :) thanks for the reply ! I got it to work, but the problem now is that when i edit column A, I need to click on column B to be able to see it say "OK" and change background color. i would want that to happen when I'm done editing column A.

Comment: (i.e without having to click on column B cell to see the changes. I know that the problem comes from the fact that isCellEditable is only invoked when I click on column B, and that's why I'd want to be abl to invoke it myself so it updates the UI) (I've tried updateUI() but it doesn't do anything).

Comment: Nevermind, found it ! I used fireTableDataChanged() in a TableModelListener and now it works :)
Thanks again for the help !