# How to color cells from JTable?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, jframe

I am kind of a newbie in Java, so my question is.
If for example I have a `JTable` which represents a 2D array of Color

```
Color [][] array = new ...
```

So then when I run the `JFrame` it shows
[image]

So how do I color it?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563799/jtable-cellrenderer-changes-backgroundcolor-of-cells-while-running/14565614#14565614) will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach a cellrenderer to your JTable and adjust the color with it:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Comment: So it is necessary to use a renderrer function

Comment: @Phil_Charly not a function, a instance of a implementation of [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html). There you can create a component which will be displayed in the cell of the table.